# infinite scroll triggers the event too many times

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to develop an infinet scroll with javascript and laravel but I'm finding that the javascript function when the scroll reaches the end is triggered multiple times, which makes it not work correctly.

The javascript code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                window.livewire.emit('load-more');
                console.log('load more');
            }
        };
   </script>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In your `load-more` event handler you should probably have some way of determining if there's more already loading to not keep calling any loading functions multiple times.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it via javascript and only emit the event once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a flag used to disable loading. Here we add a boolean `isLoading` to the window object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.isLoading = false

    window.onscroll = ev => {
      // Check scroll position
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // Check loading flag
        if(window.isLoading){
          console.log('still loading');
          return true
        }
        
        // Load more data
        window.livewire.emit('load-more');
        console.log('load more');

        // Set the flag to disable loading
        window.isLoading = true;
      }
    };
    
    // To reset the isLoading flag we'll emit an event from the Livewire component to the browser
    window.addEventListener('loading-complete', event => {
      console.log('loading complete');
      window.isLoading = false;
    })
</script>
```

As you can see above we reset the `isLoading` flag by [emitting an event to the browser from the Livewire component (see the docs)](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser):

```
public function loadData()
{
    // Load data

    // Dispatch event to frontend
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('loading-complete');
}
```